# Trying to prompt user to enter arithmetic operation and prints value according to operation chosen

Tags: python

```
x= int(input("Please enter the value of x: "))
y= int(input("Please enter the value of y: "))
operator = input("Please enter an operator you would like to complete the equation:")

if operator > '*':
  print("The result of the equation is: ", x*y)
elif operator > '+':
  print("The result of the equation is ", x+y)
elif operator > '-':
  print("The result of the equation is", x-y)
elif operator > '/':
  print("The result of the equation is ", x/y)
```

With my block of code, I am trying to get it to where it will take the operator the user inputs and completes the math equation according to what they type, and currently when I run it, it will only complete the equation using multiplication.

Comment: Please post the code into the question, not a link.

Comment: Use `'=='` instead of `'>'`!

Comment: x= int(input("Please enter the value of x: "))
y= int(input("Please enter the value of y: "))
operator = input("Please enter an operator you would like to complete the equation:")

if operator > '*':
    print("The result of the equation is: ", x*y)
elif operator > '+':
    print("The result of the equation is: ", x+y)
elif operator > '-':
    print("The result of the equation is: ", x-y)
elif operator > '/':
    print("The result of the equation is: ", x/y)

Comment: It's good that you've provided actual code.  It's bad that you've put it all in a comment.  Please update your post with the code in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking equality using '>' Operator. In python '>' is used to check greater than relation ships. to check equality use '==' operator.

```
if operator == '*':
  print("The result of the equation is: ", x*y)
elif operator == '+':
  print("The result of the equation is ", x+y)
elif operator == '-':
  print("The result of the equation is", x-y)
elif operator == '/':
  print("The result of the equation is ", x/y)
```